# Data Driven Framework - SendKeys error message - eClipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

please refer below the data driver framework code where i am facing below error message

> The method sendkeys(charsequence ) in the type webelement is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int).

Have commented them with keyword as problem.

have browsed in web including stackoverflow and below below solutions are shared.

1. Change the compiler version from old version to 1.5 or greater. - already having compiler version greater than 1.5.
2. Change the JRE version from JRE8 to JRE7. - have tried with JRE8 &JRE7 but still error exists. See below image :

[image]

This is the code :

```
package datadrivenframework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class SnapDealLogin 
{
    @Test(dataProvider = "ABN")     
    public void Snap_Login(int UserID) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\workspace\\Selenium\\browser\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver Snap = new ChromeDriver();
        Snap.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Snap.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Snap.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Snap.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sdHeader']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/span[1]")).click();
        Snap.findElement(By.xpath("//a [@href='https://www.snapdeal.com/login']")).click();
        Snap.switchTo().frame("loginIframe");
        Snap.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Snap.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(UserID); // PROBLEM
        Snap.findElement(By.id("checkUser")).click();
        Snap.quit();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "ABN")
    public Object [] Snap_Data()
    {
        Object [] login = new Object[3];
        login[0] = 777777;
        login[1] = 888888;
        login[2] = 984149104;
        return login;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error Log.

Comment: @badri, If any answer is helpful for you then please mark as `accepted` by click on right tick of answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

void sendKeys(char sequence) only accepts char sequence / String as parameter.

So you need to wirte like this `UserID+""`. [To convert it into string]

You also need to change data provider, if you return 1d array then it will throw TestNG Exception as :-

```
 Data Provider public java.lang.Object[] co.ans.Answer.Snap_Data() must return either Object[][] or Iterator<Object>[], not class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Try this code : it works fine at my end.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "ABN")

public void Snap_Login(int UserID) throws InterruptedException{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver Snap = new ChromeDriver();
Snap.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Snap.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/");
Thread.sleep(3000);
Snap.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(2000);
Snap.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sdHeader']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/span[1]")).click();
Snap.findElement(By.xpath("//a [@href='https://www.snapdeal.com/login']")).click();
Snap.switchTo().frame("loginIframe");
Snap.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Thread.sleep(1000);
Snap.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(UserID+""); // PROBLEM
Snap.findElement(By.id("checkUser")).click();
Snap.quit();
}

@DataProvider(name = "ABN")
public Object [][] Snap_Data(){
return new Object[][] {{777777},{888888},{984149104}};   
}
```

Output :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `sendKeys()` method says

> void org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence... arg0)

That means it accepts the value as character sequence or String And your are passing `int` value that why it showing you error.

Just do one thing convert that integer value to String and try. This is how you can convert using `Integer.toString()` method. Update this line code :

```
 Snap.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(UserID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As per your **`@DataProvider`** you have inserted the values as `777777`, `888888`, `984149104` into an `Array` of `Objects`. So when you are accessing the **`Objects`** in the calling method **`Snap_Login`** as `int UserID`, @Tuks solution would work for you where the `int` have been converted into `String` as in `sendKeys(Integer.toString(UserID));`

But in real time scenario the usecases will be different. **Real Mobile Numbers are of 10 digits** e.g. `7777777777`, `8888888888` or Email IDs as `badri@gmail.com`. Inthat case you will have only a single approach as follows:

The option would be to change the `Integer` values into `String` values and pass them as `String` within `Snap_Login` method, where you won't need to convert. Please find below the sample code:

```
package demo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Q45451152_DataProvider_string 
{

    @Test(dataProvider = "ABN")

    public void Snap_Login(String UserID) throws InterruptedException
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver Snap = new ChromeDriver();
    Snap.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Snap.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Snap.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Snap.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sdHeader']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/span[1]")).click();
    Snap.findElement(By.xpath("//a [@href='https://www.snapdeal.com/login']")).click();
    Snap.switchTo().frame("loginIframe");
    Snap.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Snap.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(UserID); // PROBLEM
    Snap.findElement(By.id("checkUser")).click();
    Snap.quit();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "ABN")
    public Object [] Snap_Data()
    {
    Object [] login = new Object[3];
    login[0] = "7777777777";
    login[1] = "8888888888";
    login[2] = "badri@gmail.com";
    return login;
    }
}
```

> Its worth to mention incase of **10 digit Real Time Mobile Numbers**: **`One of the shortfalls of Java is indexes for lists and arrays are int, not long so cannot be extended`**. So in your case it's would be optimized to accept only `String` from the `@DataProvider`

Let me know if this Answers your Question.